# Which files xcode4 install in the Mac system?

Tags: xcode, macos, llvm, clang

I just intalled xcode4 in mac pro. How can I check which files are installed from in the system?

There are two clang in the systems. One is in /usr/bin, and another is in /Developer/usr/bin/. Why the system maintain two copies?

The same as many other tools such as svn, llvm-gcc, yacc and so on. They both have two copies in /usr/bin and /Developer/usr/bin.

Comment: i believe you should be able to start the installer, go to "custom install", and see the binaries that will be installed.

Answer (score 1):

The developer tools are installed into /Developer. Due to historical and unixy reasons some of the tools are also installed into /usr to be consistent with existing practice.